# Flink KeyedCoProcessFunction working with state

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use `KeyedCoProcessFunction` function to enrich main datastream with data comes from another stream

Code:

```scala
class AssetDataEnrichment extends KeyedCoProcessFunction[String, PacketData, AssetCommandState, AssetData] with LazyLogging {

  case class AssetStateDoc(assetId: Option[String])
  private var associatedDevices: ValueState[AssetStateDoc] = _

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    val associatedDevicesDescriptor =
      new ValueStateDescriptor[AssetStateDoc]("associatedDevices", classOf[AssetStateDoc])
    associatedDevices = getRuntimeContext.getState[AssetStateDoc](associatedDevicesDescriptor)
  }

  override def processElement1(
                                packet: PacketData,
                                ctx: KeyedCoProcessFunction[String, PacketData, AssetCommandState, AssetData]#Context,
                                out: Collector[AssetData]): Unit = {
    
    val tmpState = associatedDevices.value
    val state = if (tmpState == null) AssetStateDoc(None) else tmpState
    
    state.assetId match {
      case Some(assetId) =>
        logger.debug(s"There are state for ${packet.tag.externalId} = $assetId")
        out.collect(AssetData(assetId, packet.tag.externalId.get, packet.toString))
      case None => logger.debug(s"No state for a packet ${packet.tag.externalId}")
      case _ => logger.debug("Smth went wrong")
    }
  }

  override def processElement2(
                                value: AssetCommandState,
                                ctx: KeyedCoProcessFunction[String, PacketData, AssetCommandState, AssetData]#Context,
                                out: Collector[AssetData]): Unit = {
    
    value.command match {
      case CREATE =>
        logger.debug(s"Got command to CREATE state for tag: ${value.id} with value: ${value.assetId}")
        logger.debug(s"current state is ${associatedDevices.value()}")
        associatedDevices.update(AssetStateDoc(Some(value.assetId)))
        logger.debug(s"new state is ${associatedDevices.value()}")
      case _ =>
        logger.error("Got unknown AssetCommandState command")
    }
  }
}
```

`processElement2()` works good, it's accept data and update a state.
but in a `processElement1()` I am always hitting `case None => logger.debug(s"No state for a packet ${packet.tag.externalId}")`

although I expect that there will be a value that was set in `processElement2` function

as an example I used this guide - `https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`processElement1` and `processElement2` do share state, but keep in mind that this is key-partitioned state. This means that a value set in `processElement2` when processing a given value *v2* will only be seen in `processElement1` when it is called later with a value *v1* having the same key as *v2*.

Also keep in mind that you have no control over the race condition between the two streams coming into `processElement1` and `processElement2`.

The [RidesAndFares exercise](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/rides-and-fares) from the official Apache Flink training is all about learning to work with this part of the API. https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/etl/ is the home for the corresponding tutorial.